# Visual Studio 2012 no place to define public variables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am just learning C# programming and I had been using Microsoft Visual 2010 express.
I loaded Visual Studio express 2012 for Windows desktop. Everything went well with the install and I started to practice some coding, and that is when I ran into an issue.

I needed to define some variables outside of the form so that they would not be restricted to a single form.
In 2010 I would place them in .cs file after the following lines:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

However in 2012 I don't have that option the as it looks like this:

```
Public Class Form1 
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

The " InitializeComponent();" is no where to be found.

If I load a project I had written in 2010 into 2012  the "InitializeComponent();"  is there and 2012 has no complaints about it.
I have tried defining public variables, etc. in different places in 2012 but with no luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Nick

Comment: Are you aware that your code samples are in two different languages? The first one is C#, the second one is Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Solution Explorer window, click on the arrow to expand the Form1.vb and the on the arrow to expand the Form1 class. You will see the missing InitializeComponent method

Alternatively you could click the button on the Solution Explorer window that has the Tooltip `Show All Files` and you will see the Form1.Designer.vb file if you exapnd again the main Form1.vb node.